# Cancelling a style sheet from certain parts of HTML

Tags: css

Is it possible to block a style sheet from effecting a certain part of an HTML document such as the footer.

I would like to block Woocommerce from going near my buttons in my footer but I don't want to disable it everywhere else.

Thanks

Comment: you can remove style by removing class/id of that block using jquery

Comment: No, if you have a style sheet linked to a page, you can't have it affect only some of the page.. You need to solve this with css classes, either override the styles with your own classes and styles, or remove the unwanted rules from the css